# SQL Access- WHERE from combobox

Tags: ms-access, combobox

I have a combobox in Access which contains some values. Selecting one of those values I want to filter records.

Right now the query I wrote looks like this:

```
SELECT Fornitori.Brand
    ,Fornitori.Mail
    ,Fornitori.Web
    ,Fornitori.Località
    ,Fornitori.[ID Categoria]
    ,Fornitori.[ID Zona]
    ,Zona.Zona
    ,Settore.Categoria
FROM Settore
INNER JOIN (
    Zona INNER JOIN Fornitori ON Zona.[ID Zona] = Fornitori.[ID Zona]
    ) ON Settore.[ID Categoria] = Fornitori.[ID Categoria]
WHERE Fornitori.[ID Categoria] = Maschere!Brandsrch!Brandcatsrchcb.Value;
```

Doing like this it filters the records when I select a value from the combobox.

My goal right now is to have no filters (like there is no WHERE clause) when I cancel the text into the combobox or at first when it is empty before I select something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something complex with VBA, or just modify your query to the following:

```
SELECT Fornitori.Brand, Fornitori.Mail, Fornitori.Web, Fornitori.Località, Fornitori.[ID Categoria], Fornitori.[ID Zona], Zona.Zona, Settore.Categoria
FROM Settore INNER JOIN (Zona INNER JOIN Fornitori ON Zona.[ID Zona] = Fornitori.[ID Zona]) ON Settore.[ID Categoria] = Fornitori.[ID Categoria]

WHERE Fornitori.[ID Categoria]=Maschere!Brandsrch!Brandcatsrchcb.Value
OR NZ(Maschere!Brandsrch!Brandcatsrchcb.Value, "") = "";
```

This returns all records when `Maschere!Brandsrch!Brandcatsrchcb.Value` is not set.

Comment: It works. Can you explain briefly what the NZ does logically?

Comment: It converts null values to an empty string, so I don't need to test both for null values and empty strings (possibly redundant, but don't know exactly how the value is set, and it can't hurt).